# how to insert "{0}" as a string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

One of the strings I want to pass into a function contains {0}, which is a placeholder escape character in c#.

What is the correct syntax to get c# to ignore this?  i tried encasing it in single quotes ('), but no good

Comment: Try `{{0}}`, should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the curly braces like this:

```
{{0}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this double curly brackets

```
{{0}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use double curly brackets.

Ex. `'{0}'` becomes `'{{0}}'`